# Re-ordering JSON data from jQuery .getJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I'm using $.getJSON to pull some data from an data source and the result comes in as JSON, but it's in this format (as it comes from a table):

```
result {
    0: Array {
       0: 'First Name',
       1: 'Last Name',
       2: 'City', 
       3: 'State'
    }
    1: Array {
       0: 'John',
       1: 'Doe',
       2: 'Portland',
       3: 'Oregon'
    }
    2: Array {
       0: 'Jane',
       1: 'Doe',
       2: 'Seattle',
       3: 'Washington'
    }
}
```

I need to get that data into something that looks more like this:

```
Object {
    'First Name': 'John', 'Jane'
    'Last Name': 'Doe', 'Doe'
    'City': 'Portland', 'Seattle'
    'State': 'Oregon', 'Washington'
}
```

I thought that I would just put these into a few $.each() loops but I can't seem to get an object with the first array's values as the keys and the matching values as items in an array assigned to that key.  I've tried something like this:

```
var tmpArray = [];
var labelKeys = [];
$.each(result, function(key, val){
    if (key < 1){
        $.each(val, function(labelKey, labelVal){
           labelKeys.push(labelVal);
        }
    } else {
        for (var i=0; i<labelKeys.length;i++){
            tmpArray[labelKeys[i]].push(val[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

That doesn't work and I get an undefined error for push().

I can separate all the arrays out into their own arrays and get them out to the console, but I can't figure out how to push data to an object or an array using a key value.

How do I push values to an object so that I can just loop through the arrays and group the objects at the same numbered location and assign it to a key that's at the same location in the first array?

Comment: You can't call `.push()` on `tmpArray[labelKeys[i]]` because it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Meaning what?  labelKeys[i] would exist after the first iteration and would never get to that second line until it did exist.  I can even add `console.log(labelKeys[i])` and it will spit out the right key.  Can you explain a little further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `.push()` on `tmpArray[labelKeys[i]]` because it doesn't exist yet.  You need to add that key to the object, before trying to call `.push()`.

```
// this needs to be an object
// arrays can only have numeric keys
var tmpArray = {};
var labelKeys = [];

$.each(result, function(key, val){
    if (key < 1){
        $.each(val, function(labelKey, labelVal){
           labelKeys.push(labelVal);
           // Create an array for this label
           tmpArray[labelVal] = [];
        });
    } else {
        for (var i=0; i<labelKeys.length;i++){
            tmpArray[labelKeys[i]].push(val[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Of course!  Cuz it's a nested array and I have initialized the "inside" array.  Bah!  Glad to get another set of eyes on this.  Thanks!

Comment: Exactly!  Glad I could help :-)

Comment: You have no idea how much of a relief your answer is.  Such a simple solution and I've been staring at this for far too long.  :(

Comment: Glad I could help :-)